# Tutorial to create a placeholder image

Tags: php, image, placeholder

i want to know how create a placeholder image service in PHP, as lorempixel.com or dummyimage.com
In particular, how to get the image from a folder and crop it depending GET parametres.
Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the GD library

Just create a new image with the width and height from the paramaters

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php

script.php?width=200&height=300

```
$width = (int)$_GET["width"];
$height = (int)$_GET["height"];
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```